# Не работает MySQL из PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Ввёл код. Выводит пустую страницу. Где ошибка? Где может быть возможная ошибка?
Заранее, спасибо

первый документ

```
<?php // login.php
$db_hostname = 'localhost';
$db_database = 'test';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '555555';
?>
```

второй документ

```
<?php // query.php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!db_server)
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " , mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " , mysql_error());
$query = 'select * from class';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result)
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " , mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($j = 0 ;  $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
echo 'Author' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'autor') . '<br/>';
echo 'Title' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'title') . '<br/>';
echo 'Category' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'category') . '<br/>';
echo 'Year' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'year') . '<br/>';
echo 'ISBN' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'isbn') . '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Что выводится в браузере (какой http-код возвращается) ? Что в логах сервера?

Comment: в браузере чистая страница

Comment: не знаю, как просмотреть логи, новичок

Comment: @Max, функции `mysql_` устарели начиная с PHP 5.5.0. Используйте `mysqli_` или `PDO`.

Comment: `die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " , mysql_error());` вместо запятой попробуйте точку `die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: ". mysql_error());`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас код кривой, в этом вся проблема, давайте разберемся.

Тут не хватает знака указания переменной $

```
if (!db_server) //меняем на if (!$db_server)
```

В die, принимается всего один параметр, Вы передаете 2 параметра, запятую заменяем точкой

```
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " , mysql_error()); 
//Меняем на
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
```

Корректный код второго файла:

```
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server)
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database)
or die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
$query = 'select * from class';
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result)
die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($j = 0 ;  $j < $rows; ++$j)
{
echo 'Author' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'autor') . '<br/>';
echo 'Title' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'title') . '<br/>';
echo 'Category' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'category') . '<br/>';
echo 'Year' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'year') . '<br/>';
echo 'ISBN' .  mysql_result($result,$j,'isbn') . '<br/>';
}
```

Если вы используете версию PHP 7, тогда у вас не будет работать данный код. Расширение mysql отключено, Вам требуется писать будет код с использованием библиотеки [PDO](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php) или [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php), иначе получите ошибку

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect()
```

А также обязательно смотрите лог ошибок сервера, чтобы точнее понять проблему. Для разработки можете включить вывод ошибок в браузер (**не делать это не продакшене, даже под дулом пистолета**)

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

Comment: спасибо, работает.

Answer (score 1):

ошибка в php коде

> **Parse error**:  syntax error, unexpected ',' in **C:\WebServers\home\localhost\orange\includes\a.php** on line **5**

Comment: спасибо всем. пробовал  mysqli_ - бесконечно грузило страницу. Поменял точки и запятые - всё нормально

Comment: Не публикуйте комментарий ответом